# How to pass extra args or context to python logger StreamHandler?

Tags: python, logging

I have my log handler (`logging.StreamHandler`) which is used to catch events from default python logger and send them to some database.

Code structure is looks like this:

```
import logger

...

class EventLogger(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLevel("WARNING")

    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> None:
        self.log("error", {"message": record.msg})

    def log(self, type_: str, data: object):
        # save data somewhere

...

logger.addHandler(container.event_logger())
```

What I want to do is to pass extra vars to `EventLogger` `emit` function or set some context and read from it in `emit` to have some extra logic.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.makeLogRecord have you tried this?